# SQL MySql Recursive Update - Set root_id by following parent_ids

Tags: mysql, recursion, recursive-query

I have two tables. Table one looks like this

```
"element"
id | name
1  | first_element
2  | second_element
3  | third_element
```

```
"element_hierarchy"
id | element_id | parent_id | root_id
1  | 2          | 1         | 1
2  | 3          | 2         | 1
```

This table says that the parent of element 3 is 2 and the parent of 2 is 1. Also, we say that 1 is the root level of this tree, there is no level above it.

My problem is that I just add the last column "root_id" and it doesn't exist just yet. So I have to fill it with data. Parent ids are already set.

I need to find a way to bake this update into the liquibase xml we are using. And it needs to work on MySql 5.6, 5.7, and 8.

I am not sure if that is even possible in a MySql Update Statement. And I start wondering if I have to do it on an application level.

Comment: Single UPDATE cannot solve in 5.x. Use iterative stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE fill_root_id ()
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE element_hierarchy ADD COLUMN root_id INT;
    UPDATE element_hierarchy SET root_id = parent_id;
    REPEAT
        UPDATE element_hierarchy t1
          JOIN element_hierarchy t2 ON t1.root_id = t2.element_id
        SET t1.root_id = t2.parent_id;
    UNTIL !ROW_COUNT() END REPEAT;
END
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mysql_5.6&fiddle=ee350274be4759cbf598534351adb3a9